# Segmentation Fault on Initial Execution Only. Cause of seg fault seems to change

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, beagleboneblack

This question is directly related to the PWM modules on the BeagleBone Black. There are two questions here related to that but instead of offering answers they offer alternatives that, in my opinion are more messy and unnecessary.

The following code is one of a number of functions used to initiate and adjust the PWM signal. The code works with one caveat, on initial execution a segmentation fault occurs. On every execution afterward there is no issue. This function is called at the beginning of another program to set up the PWM signal. Using gdb I have narrowed the issue down to the the fseek()/fprintf() functions. Originally SIGSEGV was received from the fseek() however after doing some reading I decided that to comment it out. Then the SIGSEGV was generated by the fprintf().

I am really not sure why this is occurring as there are two other functions that have the exact same setup that execute prior to this and do not cause segmentation faults.

Please take a look and let me know if anything stands out. I can post additional code if necessary.

```
int setPWMPeriod(int helpnum, char* pin, int period)
{
    FILE *pwm;
    char buf[5];
    char buf2[60] = "/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_";

    //build file path
    sprintf(buf,"%i",helpnum);
    printf("%s\n",pin);
    strcat(buf2,pin);
    strcat(buf2,".");
    strcat(buf2,strcat(buf,"/period"));

    printf("%s\n",buf2);
    pwm = fopen(buf2, "w");
    if(pwm == NULL) printf("PWM Period failed to open\n");
    fflush(pwm);
  //fseek(pwm,0,SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(pwm,"%d",period);
    fflush(pwm);
    fclose(pwm);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Some additional information. helpnum = "15", pin = "P8_13"

Comment: If you fail to open the file you shouldn't keep trying to access it. You need to return from the function when that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a buffer that can hold a 4-character string (plus `\0`):

```
char buf[5];
```

Print an `int` into it, that we hope is 4 or fewer chars long

```
sprintf(buf,"%i",helpnum);
```

And then append 7 characters:

```
strcat(buf2,    /* ---> */ strcat(buf,"/period")   /* <--- */  );
```

Overrunning the buffer so that anything can happen. Maybe we just start overwriting `buf2`, maybe we overwrite `pwm`, maybe we trash the stack...

Make `buf` as large as the longest `int` + `"/period"` string, plus 1.

Comment: yea I tried that. No dice. Would it maybe be an issue where previous functions i use the same code pwm = fopen(buf2, "w"); but I am changing buf2 ? I made sure to flush and close pwm at the ends of each function but again I am really not sure why the issue is occurring.

Comment: @Moeman69 This is one obvious bug. Your program may have multiple bugs.

Answer (score 1):

See these statements -

```
  sprintf(buf,"%i",helpnum);               //if `helpnum` is a 5 digit number then UB
  .....
  strcat(buf2,strcat(buf,"/period"));
```

`strcat(buf,"/period")` this will overflow array `buf` ,as it only has size `5` .

You need to increase size of `buf` accordingly , something like this -

```
char buf[50];
```

*Also leave space for null terminator* (`'\0'`) *as you pass it to string manipulation functions .*

**Note**- Also see if `helpnum` should not be greater then `4` digits , else it would cause undefined behaviour .

Comment: That isn't the issue I don't think, unless it is for some reason preemptive. helpnum is consistently 15. I went ahead and made the buffer larger and the segmentation fault still occurs.

Comment: @Moeman69 then you may have overflowed `buf2` ,. Cant say as we don't know how long is `pin` and other things that you append into it.

Comment: I added some additional details. helpnum is consistenly two digits (15) and pin is 5 (P8_13). I expanded both buffers to 100 and still the issue persists. So I am not sure it is buffer overflow issue. If that were the case wouldn't it occur every time? Not just on the initial run? 

Some related issues with fseek()/fprintf() and segmentation faults hinted at an address pointer issue when opening the file fails. But then I still dont understand why it would work the second time I ran it. Thoughts?

Comment: @Moeman69 Its caused  _undefined behaviour_ , so expecting same behaviour every time won't fulfil . I don't see any other problem as you also check `return` of `fopen` and it will create a new file if not present . You may need to take a look at calling function .